# How do combine priors elicited through the quantile method?

Tags: bayesian, prior

Once I have elicited priors from experts using the quantile method (i.e., what value would be equally likely to have the parameter be above and below; if the parameter were above/below that, what value would be equally likely to have the parameter be above and below).

I have found resources to create a distribution reflecting each of these in isolation. But how would I develop a single prior distribution that accounts for all of the elicited opinions?

Comment: In any case though, if they are not to be combined, is the suggestion to run a separate analysis using each elicited prior?

Comment: Is "Inference for Deterministic Simulation Models: The
 Bayesian Melding Approach" the paper you had in mind?